# Cast List Of JObject to List of .Net Object

Tags: c#, .net, json.net

how can we convert list of J Object into list of .net object ? i can do this with the help of like this

```
List<PriceSubject> lstPriceSubject = new List<PriceSubject>();

foreach (JObject obj in signalRInput.Input)
{
    PriceSubject price = obj.ToObject<PriceSubject>();
    lstPriceSubject.Add(obj);
}
```

but i want to do it in one line, is there any way to do it in one line ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the object you have as input is a JArray, you can simply do this:

```
List<PriceSubject> prices = signalRInput.ToObject<List<PriceSubject>>();
```

Comment: it's a list of JObject and not a JArray

Comment: thanks for a help i think it's a design problem from my side i have change the type of input variable from List<Object> to JArray and i can get data from signalR in this object so your solution work fine now :)